Find the radius $r$ on the circle tangent to two other circles
In the figure shown calculate $r$, if
$R= 17m$
(Answer:$4$)

I was able to calculate the radius of the circle on the right. How would you calculate the radius $r$?
$ON = x\\
s = \frac{34}{4} = 8,5\\
\triangle MO_1N: (s+t)^2 = (s+x)^2+t^2\\
s^2+2st+t^2 = s^2+2sx+x^2+t^2 \implies 2st = 2sx+x^2\\
17t = 17x + x^2(I)\\
\triangle OO_1N: (R-t)^2 = t^2+x^2 \\
R^2-2RT+t^2 = t^2+x^2 \implies R^2-2Rt = x^2\\
289-34t = x^2 \implies 289- 2(17t) =x^2 \\
De(I): 289 - 2(17x+x^2) = x^2 \implies 3x^2+34x-289=0\\
{x = -17} \vee x = \frac{17}{3}
de(I): 17t = 17.\frac{17}{3}+ (\frac{17}{3})^2\\
t = \frac{17}{3}+\frac{17}{9} = \frac{68}{9}$


You've made a great start, with this answer continuing from that. The following is your diagram with several lines, points and line lengths added:

In particular, I've added $OP$ (which goes through $O_2$ as $P$ is a tangent point) and $O_{1}O_{2}$, the vertical line $O_{2}Y$ with $Y$ on $AB$, and the horizontal line $XO_{1}$, with $X$ on $O_{2}Y$. In addition, $h = \lvert O_{2}Y\rvert$ and $w = \lvert MY\rvert$.
The semiperimeter of $\triangle MOO_{2}$ is
$$s = \frac{\lvert MO\rvert + \lvert MO_2\rvert + \lvert OO_2\rvert}{2} = \frac{8.5 + (8.5 + r) + (17 - r)}{2} = 17$$
Thus, equating the one-half base times height triangle area formula with that from Heron's formula gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{8.5h}{2} & = \sqrt{17(17 - 8.5)(17 - (8.5 + r))(17 - (17 - r))} \\
\frac{8.5h}{2} & = \sqrt{2(8.5)(8.5)(8.5 - r)r} \\
h & = 2\sqrt{17r - 2r^2} \\
h^2 & = 4(17)r - 8r^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Using the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle MYO_2$, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
w^2 & = (8.5 + r)^2 - h^2 \\
w^2 & = 8.5^2 + 17r + r^2 - (4(17r) - 8r^2) \\
w^2 & = 9r^2 - 3(17)r + 8.5^2 \\
w^2 & = (3r - 8.5)^2 \\
w & = \lvert 3r - 8.5\rvert
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
The following assumes that $3r - 8.5 \gt 0$, since we know $r = 4$, with checking the case where $3r - 8.5 \lt 0$ being left for anybody interested. Since you've determined that $\lvert ON\rvert = \frac{17}{3}$, we thus have
$$\lvert XO_1\rvert = \lvert YN\rvert = \lvert MN\rvert - w = 8.5 + \frac{17}{3} - (3r - 8.5) = -3r + \frac{4(17)}{3}$$
Using that $\lvert O_{2}X\rvert = \lvert O_{2}Y\rvert - \lvert O_{1}N\rvert = h - \frac{68}{9}$ and $O_{1}O_{2} = r + \frac{68}{9}$, then the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle O_{1}XO_{2}$ gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(-3r + \frac{4(17)}{3}\right)^2 + \left(h - \frac{68}{9}\right)^2 & = \left(r + \frac{68}{9}\right)^2 \\
9r^2 - 8(17)r + \frac{16(289)}{9} + h^2 - \frac{136h}{9} + \left(\frac{68}{9}\right)^2 & = r^2 + \frac{136r}{9} + \left(\frac{68}{9}\right)^2 \\
8r^2 - 8(17)r + \frac{16(289)}{9} + (4(17)r - 8r^2) - \frac{136h}{9} & = \frac{136r}{9} \\
- 4(17)r + \frac{16(289)}{9} - \frac{136h}{9} & = \frac{136r}{9} \\
-9r + 4(17) - 2h & = 2r \\
-11r + 4(17) & = 2h \\
121r^2 - 8(11)(17)r + (4(17))^2 & = 16(17)r - 32r^2 \\
153r^2 - 104(17)r + (4(17))^2 & = 0 \\
9r^2 - 104r + 16(17) & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
The discriminant is $104^2 - 4(104)9 = 1024 = 32^2$, so the quadratic formula gives that $r = \frac{104 \pm 32}{18}$, i.e., $r = 4$ or $r = \frac{68}{9}$. Since $r \lt t = \frac{68}{9}$, this means that $r = 4$ is the solution.

I was just going to suggest a similar thing: Using Heron's formula in $[MO_1O_2]+[MOO_1]=[MOO_2]+[OO_1O_2]$ to get an equation including $r$ because all sides of those triangles can be written as expressions of $r$. However that would be some tedious work.

Thanks for help

It suffices to apply Descartes' theorem:
$$
k_{4}=k_{1}+k_{2}+k_{3}\pm 2{\sqrt {k_{1}k_{2}+k_{2}k_{3}+k_{3}k_{1}}},
$$
where:
$$
k_1=-{1\over17},\quad k_2={2\over17},\quad k_3={9\over68}
$$
(note that $k_1<0$ because the large circle circumscribes the other two).
A straightforward computation gives then
$$
k_4={1\over4}\quad\text{or}\quad k_4={9\over68}.
$$
The second solution corresponds to the reflection of the third circle about the diameter of the large circle, hence the solution of interest is the first one, giving $r=4$.

thanhs for help
